# User Form not showing django class based views

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am working on Hospital Management System and there are 5-6 different types of users like Patient, Doctor, Nurse, Accountant, Receptionist, etc. I've extended the User model using `AbstractUser` which has common fields for all users like DoB, address, etc.
`models.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # user_type       = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPES, default='patient', max_length=20)
    date_of_birth   = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_future_date])
    phone_regex     = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+9199999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    mobile_num      = models.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[phone_regex])
    created         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_joining    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    photo           = models.ImageField(default="default.png", upload_to="patients/%Y/%m/%d", blank=True)
   # other fields

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}({self.username})"


class Staff(models.Model):
    aadhar_number   = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Aadhar Number')
    empCategory     = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name='Employee Category')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Patient(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_discharge   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    allergies           = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}({self.user.username})"

class Doctor(models.Model):
    DEPARTMENTS = [('Cardiologist', 'Cardiologist'),
                    ('Dermatologists', 'Dermatologists'),
                    ('Emergency Medicine Specialists', 'Emergency Medicine Specialists'),
                    ('Allergists/Immunologists', 'Allergists/Immunologists'),
                    ('Anesthesiologists', 'Anesthesiologists'),
                    ('Colon and Rectal Surgeons', 'Colon and Rectal Surgeons')
                ]
    user        = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    languages   = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    speciality  = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    department  = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DEPARTMENTS)    
    # patients    = models.ManyToManyField(Patient, related_name='doctors')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}({self.user.username})"
    

class Receptionist(Staff):
    user    = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # patient = models.ManyToManyField(Patient, related_name='receptionists', blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name}"

class Nurse(Staff):
    user  = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Nurses'

class Accountant(Staff):
    user  = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`forms.py`

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    class Meta:
        # gives current active model either Custom User or default User model
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                  'date_of_birth', 'photo', 'mobile_num', 'gender',
                  'father_name', 'mother_name', 'blood_group', 'marital_status',
                  'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'zipcode', 'state'
                  ]
        exclude = ['groups', 'superuser_status',
                   'is_staff', 'is_superuser', ]

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return cd['password2']


class PatientRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['allergies']
        exclude = ['user', ]
```

`views.py`

```
class UserRegistrationMixin(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    template_name = 'accounts/register.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_form'] = self.form_class
        return context

    def get(self, request):
        user_form = self.form_class
        return self.render_to_response({'user_form':user_form})
    
    def post(self, request):
        user_form = self.form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            password = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            new_user.set_password(password)
            new_user.save()
            messages.success(request, f'New user "{new_user}" created!')
        return self.render_to_response({'user_form':user_form})

class PatientRegistrationView(UserRegistrationMixin, CreateView):
    profile_form_class = PatientRegistrationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profile_form'] = self.profile_form_class
        return context


    def get(self, request):
        profile_form = self.profile_form_class
        return self.render_to_response({'profile_form':profile_form})
    
    def post(self, request):
        profile_form = self.profile_form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            # Patient.objects.create()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = new_user
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Profile for user "{new_user}" created!')
        return self.render_to_response({'profile_form':profile_form})
```

I am trying to separate common logic for registering users and creating profiles for each user i.e.  `UserRegistrationMixin` has logic to create a user and  `PatientRegistrationView` will create a patient's profile and its permissions. But when I inherit from  `UserRegistrationMixin`, user_form doesn't show. I don't have much experience in Django's GCBV. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `get` method. The `get_context_data` doesn't called. You can check the `get` method of `View` class:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Handle GET requests: instantiate a blank version of the form."""
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

You can call `context = self.get_context_data()` and pass the `context` to `render_to_response`.